# Google Glass Character limit in a static card

Tags: api, view, google-gdk, mirror, aero-glass

I trying to explore Google Glass.

I have a question what the character limit for the card view and what will happen if the text is more than character limit.

kindly advice me if any one has the actual Glass and explored this View.

Thank & Regards.
Nagendra.

Comment: The card has an auto text sizing feature to it. Once you hit a specific amount of characters it will then automatically re-size the font to fit the text. However, I don't know what the absolute max of the card is.

Comment: The font that used in cards by default is not monospace, so I don't think there is any limit by number of characters. From the other side, if the text is too long it will just get paged.